# Stopping remote debugging also stops the application itself, how to avoid this?

Tags: c#, windows, remote-debugging, windows-server-2016

I'm setting my first steps in remote debugging, and I'm debugging a C# application.
Both computers (mine and the remote one) are Windows computers, mine is Windows-10 and the remote is Windows Server 2016 standard.

Stopping the remote debugging (session) has also stopped the application itself, but I have no idea how this went down:

- Did we stop the "msvsmon.exe" without detaching the application on the remote computer?
- Did we stop the "msvsmon.exe" in the task manager instead of using its client?
  ...

I realise that, in order to stop a remote debugging session, first we need to detach our development environment, then use the "msvsmon.exe" client to stop the remote debugging and only then can we use the task manager for stopping the "msvsmon.exe" process totally, but I'd like to know that, when you don't following this procedure very strictly, why this might cause your application being finished.

Does anybody have some insight on this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Visual Studio -> Debug -> Detach All